# Why do some celestial objects "pulse" on the Galaxy Map?

Tags: mass-effect-andromeda

Why do some celestial objects "pulse" on the Galaxy Map?

What I mean is in this screenshot, only one object is pulsing like this and this is the asteroid I've just finished on:

[image: Screenshot of the Galaxy Map]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pulsing indicates there is an outstanding quest of any type at that location. The pulsing occurs on all levels of the Galaxy Map (cluster, system, etc):

[image: Pulsing on the cluster level of the Galaxy Map]

Note that "priority ops" will always detail the quest name on the Galaxy Map, as well as your currently selected journal entry, but the rest will only show if you fly all the way to the planet, before selecting the landing site, on the left of the screen.